# A gift to offer

Tags: riddle

> For months they agonized over and crafted it, this gift to me they bestowed
>
> It is precious to me, not something that could ever be bought or sold
>
> Forever mine from that day, it can never be taken from me, only given away.
>
> Yet I wanted more, and less, and so with time I crafted more in its mold.
>
> ---
>
> I share my gift readily with those whose friendship is my goal
>
> And in truth they would be shown to use it more readily then I in any poll
>
> Even if it were something I wished to shield it's a thing others have the right to wield
>
> It's forever mine, yet others claim equal ownership over it, in part and in whole
>
> ---
>
> On this day I offer you part of this gift again, but this time so different from the past
>
> I offer more, by offering less, a meager part of the whole, just the tiny bit that is last
>
> A fraction of this thing I don't solely own, so little a thing anyone could clone
>
> Yet this meager offering is more sacred to me than any riches I have amassed

What 'gift' is the poet planning to offer?

Comment: Did you mean: "Yet this meager...*than...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess the poet is offering up

> **their name.**

```
For months they agonized over and crafted it, this gift to me they bestowed
```

> Parents often wrestle over what name to give their child, and have - well - up to 9 months to finalize that decision, usually.

```
It is precious to me, not something that could ever be bought or sold
```

> A name is yours, not something that can be bought or sold, and is (literally) who you are.

```
Forever mine from that day, it can never be taken from me, only given away.
```

> You can give someone your name (by telling them what your name is). Also, in many cultures people traditionally give their spouse their name, or give up their name, at their marriage.

```
Yet I wanted more, and less, and so with time I crafted more in it's mold.
```

> Children take their parents' surname - so their name is both more, and less, than their parents' but is in the same "mold".

```
I share my gift readily with those who's friendship is my goal
```

> You tell your name to someone you want to be friends with.

```
And in truth they would be shown to use it more readily then I in any poll
```

> You don't say your own name that often, compared to others saying your name.

```
Even if It were something I wished to shield it's a thing others have the right to wield
```

> You can't really stop people from referring to you by name, even if it's to bad-mouth you.

```
It's forever mine, yet others claim equal ownership over it, in part and in whole
```

> It's your name, but others may have the same name (in whole),  and certainly others will have your surname (in part).

```
I offer you part of this gift again, but this time different from the past
```

> The poet may be proposing, thus offering up part of their name to their intended,

```
I offer more, by offering less, a meager part of the whole, just the tiny bit that is last
```

> ... offering their last name,

```
A fraction of this thing I don't solely own, so little a thing anyone could clone
```

> ... the surname they share with their family but which is not something anyone can protect others from adopting.

```
Yet this meager offering more sacred to me then any riches I have amassed
```

> The offering is of marriage, a precious thing - to share the poet's life intimately.

Comment: You don't *only* tell it to someone you want to be friends with, Inigo Montoya ;-)

Comment: I didn't say "only" :)

Comment: For the record the last line of the first stanza, I had specifically phrased it mostly thinking about nicknames, getting 'more' names by getting less, shorter, ones to use.  It worked well as part of the first stanza, the latter two sort of made it feel out of place, as the third stanza I added later changed what the poem was really asking about it just feels a little odd having the one line distraction.  But I'd wasted enough time making this up and figured I should go do something productive so I left in a clue I liked in issolation even if it felt a little odd in context heh